# "Even though it supports DirectX 11, the feature level is only 10_0, which can be problematic with many DirectX 11 & DirectX 12 titles"

Tags: directx

[image]

Can I get an explanation for this? I don't quite understand the deal with this. If it supports DirectX 11, why is the feature level 10_0? What's the difference between feature level and DirectX version?

https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-9600m-gt.c1518

Comment: Here is the table of the feature level and what features are mandatory/optional/not required for each level: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_levels_in_Direct3D

Comment: Thanks Robert, I haven't read everything yet, but it doesn't answer my question, would you have any idea as to why it says that it supports DirectX 11 but only up to feature level 10_0? If the answer's already in the links you sent, then I apologise for asking again.

Comment: The simplest explanation.  The statement is false.  Outside of that Nvidia likely simply didn't want to support it.   The statement indicated the GPU itself supported it, but more than just the GPU has to support it, the physical card must be capable.  In your case the GPU is a mobile product, so it was integrated, which means there other factors to consided.

Comment: From my interpretation DirectX 11 level 10_0 means: The driver model of DirectX 11 is supported but only the smallest possible set of DirectX 10 features -> it is a DX10 card that works with DX11 drivers.

Comment: @Robert - It's more nuanced than that.  Since the shader between 11_0 and 10_0 is indeed different.  Most DX10 capable cards could support 11_0 which was new feature (that wasn't included in DX10) that didn't require hardware support.  While 10_0 was literally DX10 features. 11_1 features required hardware and was consider DX11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I get an explanation for this?

Direct X and Vulcan both require hardware support.  DirectX itself is backward compatible starting with DirectX 10.  This means DirectX 12 can run DirectX 10 instead of requiring multiple installations of DirectX.  Additionally, DirectX is built-into Windows itself, instead of being a separate installation.

The quote basically means that Nvidia decided to only release drivers that supported the 10_0 feature level.

> I don't quite understand the deal with this. If it supports DirectX 11, why is the feature level 10_0?

Nvidia didn't want that particular GPU to support the 11_0 feature level.  It's also possible that the quote isn't accurate.

> What's the difference between feature level and DirectX version?

The following chart explain that difference in detail:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Source: [Feature support for feature levels 12_1 through 9_3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro#feature-support-for-feature-levels-12_1-through-9_3)

Comment: While I could have spent the time creating the table myself using that new SE feature.  That would have taken over an hour on such a large table.  I wasn't willing to invest that amount of time at this time.